# Find an open popup in Flex 4

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

I'm opening popups (subclass of TitleWindow) in Flex by using

```
PopUpManager.createPopUp(parent, TrainCard)
```

Is there any way I can get a list of popups that are open? Or do I need to keep my own list?
I need to make sure I'm not opening the same popup twice.

Answer (score 1):

The [ISystemManager.popUpChildren](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform//reference/actionscript/3/mx/managers/ISystemManager.html#popUpChildren) property might be what you're looking for, PopUpManager will add the popup there.  You can access the application ISystemManager via any component's [systemManager](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform//reference/actionscript/3/mx/core/UIComponent.html#systemManager) property.

Comment: systemManager was the right place to look.
systemManager.popUpChildren.numChildren is always 0 for me, don't know why. But I found the popups via systemManager.getChildAt(index). Just iterating over all children and picking those that are of my popups class.